# PHP Create XML CDATA Section which contains the result of a function

Tags: php, xml, cdata

I would like my CDATA section display the result of a function that generates a text from an sql query.

**Create sql query and call function createXMLfile:**

```
    $statement = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1");
    $statement->execute();

    $eventArray = array();

    while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        array_push($eventArray, $row);
    }
    createXMLfile($eventArray);
```

**Function that generate text from my sql query:**

```
        <?php

        function write_records($eventArray) {

          for($i=0; $i<count($eventArray); $i++){
      
            $name = $eventArray[$i]['event_name'];
            $city = $eventArray[$i]['event_city'];
                
            ?>A new event <?php echo $eventArray[$i]['event_name'];?> is coming in <?php $eventArray[$i]['event_city'];?>.<?php
    
          }
          return $eventArray;
       }
       ?>
```

**Function that create XML file (i use implode for convert array to a string):**

```
function createXMLfile($eventArray){
  
    $filePath = 'event.xml';

    $content = implode(' ', write_records($eventArray));

    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8'); 
 
    $root = $dom->createElement('INCIDENTS'); 
 
    for($i=0; $i<count($eventArray); $i++){

        $eventName = $eventArray[$i]['event_name'];

        $eventCity = $eventArray[$i]['event_city'];

        $eventXml = $dom->createElement('INCIDENT');

        $name = $dom->createElement('EVENT', $eventName); 
 
        $eventXml->appendChild($name); 
 
        $city = $dom->createElement('CITY', $eventCity); 
 
        $eventXml->appendChild($city);

        $eventXml->appendChild(new DOMElement('COMMENTAIRE'))->appendChild(new DOMCdataSection($content));

        $root->appendChild($eventXml);
 
    }
 
    $dom->appendChild($root); 
 
    $dom->save($filePath); 
 
}
```

XML file is generated but CDATA section display only this :

```
<![CDATA[Array]]>
```

Please can you tell me what's wrong ? Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:**

```
function createXMLfile($eventArray){
  
    $filePath = 'event.xml';

    $content = implode(' ', write_records($eventArray[0]));

    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8'); 
 
    $root = $dom->createElement('INCIDENTS'); 
 
    for($i=0; $i<count($eventArray); $i++){

        $eventName = $eventArray[$i]['event_name'];

        $eventCity = $eventArray[$i]['event_city'];

        $eventXml = $dom->createElement('INCIDENT');

        $name = $dom->createElement('EVENT', $eventName); 
 
        $eventXml->appendChild($name); 
 
        $city = $dom->createElement('CITY', $eventCity); 
 
        $eventXml->appendChild($city);

        $eventXml->appendChild(new DOMElement('COMMENTAIRE'))->appendChild(new DOMCdataSection($content));

        $root->appendChild($eventXml);
 
    }
 
    $dom->appendChild($root); 
 
    $dom->save($filePath); 
 
}
```

Now sql values are displayed in CDATA section but not the generated text from function write_records($eventArray).

```
<![CDATA[concert Miami]]>
```

And i would like :

```
<![CDATA[A new concert is coming in Miami]]>
```

print_r($eventArray); give me same result :

```
$statement = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1");
$statement->execute();

$eventArray = array();

while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    array_push($eventArray, $row);
}
print_r($eventArray);
createXMLfile($eventArray);
```

Apache Log say PHP Notice: *Undefined offset :0* from variables values in function write_records($eventArray)

Comment: Where have you defined `$content`?

Comment: sorry it was a mistake when I wrote the post. Question has been rectified. In my code $content is well defined

Comment: Can you `print_r($eventArray)` (right before `createXMLfile($eventArray);`) and update your question with the contents so we can see what it contains?

Comment: The reason you get `Array ` is because `$eventArray` is a multidimentional array and `implode(' ', write_records($eventArray));` won't work on those. If you want to implode the values, you need to use: `$content = implode(' ', write_records($eventArray[0]));` (since your array only contains one record). If you make sure you [display all errors and warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display?rq=1) (or check your error log), you should see some "Array to string conversion" warnings.

Comment: I need a way to display generated text by function write_records($eventArray) in the CDATA section. I'm not sure i need tu use implode() for that.
Any advice is appreciated.